# How to read multiple lines in string until specified character in C

Tags: c, string

Need to read everything until say *** comes up:

Input:

```
Hey there
how are
you
***
```

Output:

```
Hey there
how are
you
```

Would have used `scanf("%[^***]s)` but can't read all lines at once.
Only having basic C knowledge

Comment: read line by line??

Comment: Read about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). Do note that `fgets` can add the newline in the buffer.

Comment: Haven't studied strcmp

Comment: is the input source a **file**?

Comment: Then it's a good time to learn how to use it, because you'll need it fairly often when dealing with strings.

Comment: The 3 asterisks are alone in one line or we can have something lile this: 'asasasas***rtrtrtrtr' ?

Comment: @Ashish _Haven't studied strcmp_. So what are you waiting ? Study it, it's not hard.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is read one line at a time (with a funcion such as `fgets` instead of scanf) and then see if the line that you last read is equal to `***`. You can use use `strcmp` to do that but you can also do it by hand if you are not allowed to use strcmp for some reason.